# Image file not found error in laravel view to excel plugin

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel, laravel-excel

I am using Laravel plugin [Laravel Excel](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/blade) to load view directly into excel sheet. Everything goes fine. But while using image in my view, error prompts saying the full url of the image not found. Error is:

> PHPExcel_Exception
>
> File http://example.com/client1_site/public/uploads/patients/23/first-patient-photo.jpg
>   not found!

But the url exists and it displays the proper image.

I have following html in my view:

```
<td>
    @if(!is_null($s->photo))
        <img src="{{URL::to($s->photo)}}" style="width:90px;height:85px;" alt=""/>
    @endif
</td>
```

Anyone having embedded image in excel using the laravel-excel plugin experienced the same?

Answer (score 3):

I've tested it and it seems you only can use relative paths when you want to attach file to `Laravel Excel`.

So you cannot use for example:

but you should use:

```
<img src="img/ph4.png" style="width:90px;height:85px;" alt=""/>
```

I've prepared test code to make it work both for Laravel Excel and for normal route if necessary:

`routes.php` file

```
Route::get('/', function() {

    Excel::create('New file', function($excel) {

        $excel->sheet('New sheet', function($sheet) {

            $sheet->loadView('hello')->with('no_asset', true);

        });

    })->download('xls');
});


Route::get('/test', function() {

    return View::make('hello');
});
```

`hello.blade.php` file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
info here
</td>


<td>

@if (isset($no_asset))
    <img src="img/ph4.png" style="width:90px;height:85px;" alt=""/>
@else
    <img src="{{ asset('img/ph4.png') }}" style="width:90px;height:85px;" alt=""/>
@endif
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Passing extra variable `no_asset` to view you may decide inside view if you display only relative path or whole path ussing `asset`.

It's working for me - both using `/test` route I get expected result and for `/` I recieve excel file with image.

Answer (score 1):

Use pulic_path() it returns the fully qualified path to the resources directory.

```
<td>
    @if(!is_null($s->photo))
        <img src="{{ public_path().$s->photo }}" style="width:90px;height:85px;" alt=""/>
    @endif
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue and solved it with `public_path()`. In my case

```
<img src="{{ public_path().'/image/sample.png' }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used following `URL`:

```
File http://example.com/client1_site/public/uploads/patients/23/first-patient-photo.jpg
```

But if this is in your `public` folder then the `URL` should be:

```
File http://example.com/uploads/patients/23/first-patient-photo.jpg
```

Use [asset](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers) helper method instead:

```
<img src="{{ asset('uploads/patients/23/first-patient-photo.jpg')}}" style="width:90px;height:85px;" alt=""/>
```

Use the path after `public`, adjust it in your code according to this rule.

Comment: http://example.com in my case is http://localhost. Since stackoverflow won't allow localhost, I instead chose example.com. So apache's folder client_site will be actually a part of the URL before public. Even with the asset() way, same image url is generated. And same error.

Comment: Same issue here - did you manage to solve it please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<img src="public/uploads/patients/23/first-patient-photo.jpg" />`